# Logical Circuit

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

Does somebody know about how to simulate this in Mathematica? I want to give Mathematica the two Inputvalues x,y and it should output c,s.

[image]
$$c=x\land y$$
$$s=x\veebar y$$
$$x,y\in \{0,1\}$$

Comment: It seems pretty easy. Have you seen the [docs for the logical operators](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RelationalAndLogicalOperators.html) and [BooleanTable](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BooleanTable.html)?

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer my question. Booleantable gives me the possibility to output all possible solutions but not the output I get with a specific Input.

Comment: For *AND* you can use `And` and for *XOR* you can use `Xor`

Answer (score 1):

```
{c, s} = {And[x,y], Xor[x,y]}
```

or as a function of `x` and `y`:

```
f[x_,y_]:={And[x,y], Xor[x,y]}
```

Comment: BooleanFunction::bspec: BooleanFunction[True,{True,False}] is not a valid BooleanFunction specification. >>

Comment: @Maddi Restart your mathematica session and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = {BitAnd@##, BitXor@##} &;
f @@ {1, 1}
f @@@ {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}

(*
{1, 0}
{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}
*)
```